# findAll() sequelize returns in unexpected order

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to list all the data related to a table responsible for saving messages on a chat page using the sequelize ORM, but the attributes are being listed in alphabetical order according to the data in the "textcontent" column and not in order of creation, how I want it to happen.

**The method I used to list all messages in rest api**

```
async index(req, res) {
    try {
      const message = await Text.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'msghour', 'created_at', 'useremail', 'textcontent'],
        order: [['textcontent', 'DESC'], ['useremail', 'DESC'],  ['created_at', 'DESC'],  ['id', 'DESC']],
      }); 
      return res.json(message);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.json(null);
    }
  }
```

[These messages and the data related to them should not be here but at the end, as they are among the most recent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNHoe.png)

I've already tried writing just the id in the "order" array but the order of the data returned is still wrong.

`order: [['id', 'DESC']],`

I have also tried to list all the attributes in ascending order but without success.

`order: [['textcontent', 'ASC'], ['useremail', 'ASC'],  ['created_at', 'ASC'],  ['id', 'ASC']],`

Update:

I managed to solve the problem. I discovered that part of it was because of a middleware that I put in the message routes file or because of the git command that I used to send the api updates to the server.
The code that worked in the message controller was this:

```
async index(req, res) {
    try {
      const message = await Text.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'msghour', 'created_at', 'useremail', 'textcontent'],
        order: [['created_at', 'DESC']],
      });
      return res.json(message);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.json(null);
    }
  }
```

Comment: At the screenshot I see the exact order that you indicated in the query: 1. by `textcontent` descending (means z -> y -> x), 2. then by `useremail` (same for both `x`) 3. then by `created_at` from the latest to oldest (DESC order).

Comment: See the request for the line with id 88, it is not in sequence, it should be above all messages with an id number greater than its own but it is there only because of the "y" in the textcontent. For example, if I send a message that starts with "c", it will be in the middle of other messages that start with "c", regardless of their id number. The created_at time also differs on this line. Since the registration was made an hour ago, it should be above the other three

Comment: Is the screenshot was for `order: [['textcontent', 'DESC'], ['useremail', 'DESC'],  ['created_at', 'DESC'],  ['id', 'DESC']]`? If so then it's ok. 88 has `textcontent`=`y` which should go before `x` and after `z` (which is exactly like on the screenshot).